# Can an ABSENCE of heat be generated?

Tags: thermodynamics

Does there exist a device that converts electrical energy to COLD ? (Without also creating a greater amount of heat) ?

Comment: What about refrigerators and air conditioners?  Also, you cool a device by removing heat from it. You do not create heat (unless you are using an electrical heater). Since no devices are 100% efficient, you will need to remove more heat than absolutely necessary.

Comment: Not exectly what you were asking, but might be of intrest: Check the Seebeck-effect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect . Here an temperature difference can be used to convert some of the heat into electrical energy.

Comment: The law of conservation of energy is violated if consume electrical energy to remove thermal energy.

Comment: Refrigerators generate more heat than cold.

Answer (score 13):

> Does there exist a device that converts electrical energy to COLD ?

A thermoelectric cooler (TEC) can "produce cold" by pumping heat away from one side and to the other side, powered by an electric current.

> (Without also creating a greater amount of heat) ?

No, thermodynamics tells you this isn't possible. Specifically, [Carnot's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot%27s_theorem_(thermodynamics)) tells us that no heat pump is more efficient than the idealized Carnot cycle, which has efficiency $1-\frac{T_C}{T_H}$ when operating between temperatures $T_C$ and $T_H$.

Answer (score 2):

There are devices and systems that can convert electrical energy into energy used to cool; but I think it's important to know what cooling is.

Cooling is the opposite of heating; both of which are just terms that describe how thermal energy is travelling in the system.

You cannot convert *anything* "into cold".  What you can do is remove heat from it, so that it begins to cool.  To do this, you have to *transfer* the heat.

This means that if you were cooling an object; the heat you remove has to go into your surroundings.  This *could* be what you meant by "creating a greater amount of heat".

There are plenty of devices and processes that convert electrical energy to cooling power (by driving more heat out of the system than would naturally leave).  Examples include heat pumps, cooling towers, TECs (like The Photon mentioned), and several other thermodynamic solutions.

Basically, there aren't really devices that "create" new cooling and heat from electricity; but there are plenty that can transfer heat (creating a hot and cold area) using electricity.

Comment: "Basically, there aren't really devices that "create" new cooling and heat from electricity; but there are plenty that can transfer heat (creating a hot and cold area) using electricity." - minor quibble: electricity can be trivially converted to heat through joule heating (like a space heater does). There is no cold reservoir in this case, but there doesn't need to be one because the system entropy is increasing - no laws of thermodynamics are broken.